# Eval/Binding DropDownList in DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, detailsview

I have a dropdownlist inside a detailsview that is getting its values from one table and binding the selected values to a different table.  The problem I am having is that whenever postback occours the table that I am getting the ddl values from is changed back to the default read.  This makes the value that was selected always change to null (which is the first value of the list)

I have tried putting !IsPostBack in the page_load:

```
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
        DetailsView1.DataBind();
   }
```

I do have a second ddl that is dependent on the first list but that one is working fine, it is the first list that always is null and wont hold the selected value.

Here is the first ddl:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
    AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SQLLEAVECODE" DataTextField="LEAVETYPE" 
    DataValueField="LEAVECODE" Height="18px" style="text-transform:uppercase;"
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
    SelectedValue='<%# bind("reqleavecode") %>' Width="145px">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

I can't seem to figure this out, I think it may have something to do with my binding.

```
    public string lvtype;
    public string lvrequest;

    private DataSet GetData()
    {
        ConnectionStringSettingsCollection cssc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;

        var sql = "SELECT LEAVETYPE, LEAVECODE FROM TESTBWTIME.BWLVTYPE ORDER BY LEAVECODE";

        using (iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.DeriveParameters();

                using (iDB2DataAdapter da = new iDB2DataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);

                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String GetConnectionString()
    {
        ConnectionStringSettingsCollection cssc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;

        return cssc["connStringNET"].ToString();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList6"));
        DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList5"));
        DataSet ds = GetData();
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ddl1.DataSource = ds;
            ddl1.DataBind();
            lvtype = ddl1.SelectedValue;

            ddl2.DataSource = ds;
            ddl2.DataBind();
            lvrequest = ddl2.SelectedValue;
        }
        else
        {
            lvtype = ddl1.SelectedValue;
            lvrequest = ddl2.SelectedValue;
        }
       }
```

Comment: is the dropdownlist rendered in the itemtemplate and edittemplate? and does this post back call the method that populates the detailsview?

Comment: The dropdownlist is rendered only in the <InsertItemTemplate> the details view is always only going to be in Insert mode.  So I am not sure about where I happen to be populating it? I send the information entered into it to a table handled by a data handler.

Comment: Does "reqleavecode" contain unique data?

Comment: no, it is defined as a character allowing two ... it would be like : "1F" or "4 "

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same issue, I solve it using the following technique. Please modify this code according to your need. Basically you need two variables at the top i-e global to that class. And then you can get the selected value of dropdownlist in Postback and selected indexed changed event like following;

```
public string vendorId;
public string categoryId;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        dropDownListVendor.DataSource = CatalogAccess.GetVendors();
        dropDownListVendor.DataBind();
        vendorId = dropDownListVendor.SelectedValue;

        dropDownListCategory.DataSource = CatalogAccess.GetCategoriesInVendor(vendorId);
        dropDownListCategory.DataBind();
        categoryId = dropDownListCategory.SelectedValue;
    }
    else
    {
        vendorId = dropDownListVendor.SelectedValue;
        categoryId = dropDownListCategory.SelectedValue;
    }
}

protected void dropDownListVendor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        dropDownListCategory.DataSource = CatalogAccess.GetCategoriesInVendor(vendorId);
        dropDownListCategory.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I almost have it modified correctly, the only thing i was unsure of was this line: dropDownListVendor.DataSource = CatalogAccess.GetVendors();  specifically the CatalogAccess.GetVendors() it wasn't working with my getData() method mostly because I was unsure what my equivalent to CatalogAccess would be.

Comment: this is basicall a datatable that is returned from DataAccessLayer. You can bind your datatable directly here

Comment: I edited my code above to show what I was doing. If you could give me some more guidance